# C# custom control implementing existing controls

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have build a custom control thats inherited from datagridview.  I need to add several other controls (a few textboxes, buttons, etc) however since I inherited from datagridview it takes up the whole rectangle(draw area).
I have been looking for an example or method to do the following:
Draw the datagridview (custom control) but also draw several buttons below it.

I feel like I need to instead inherit from the default windows form control and then draw the datagridview in one section of it and the buttons on the other section.  However in my searching I havent found a way to do this.  Maybe I'm searching the wrong question or am looking at it the wrong way.  How can I create a custom control that has several existing controls painted onto it?

Comment: sounds like a User Control is what you are after

Comment: Yeah.  Thanks you done some searching and seems to be correct.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: As plutonix said, you don't want to inherit from grid, you want to create an UserControl and add a grid and all the controls you need.

Answer (score 3):

You could inherit from TableLayoutPanel and add the custom DataGridView control in one cell, and the other required controls in the other cells.

This would allow you to use this class as one all-encompassing control, with your inbuilt DataGridView control and the required buttons contained within it.

For example:

```
// Using Statements.

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyControl : TableLayoutPanel
    {
        // Declare instances of the controls you need.
        CustomDataGridView myDataGridControl;
        Button button1;
        Button button2;
        // etc...

        public MyControl()
        {
            // Define TableLayoutPanel properties here,
            // e.g. columns, rows, sizing...

            myDataGridControl = new CustomDataGridView();
            // Define your custom DataGridView here.

            button1 = new Button();
            // First button properties.

            button2 = new Button();
            // Second button properties.

            // Assign these controls to TableLayoutPanel
            // in the specified cells.
            Controls.Add(myDataGridControl, 0, 0);
            Controls.Add(button1, 0, 1);
            Controls.Add(button2, 1, 1);
        }

        // Methods etc...
    }
}
```